# Android using EventBus not updating another view after posting

Tags: android, kotlin, greenrobot-eventbus

I need to send a data from fragment B to A and add items to the `Recyclerview` inside of the Fragment A, so I'm using the `EventBus` to send the data and updating the list, the problem is, it only works in Debugging line by line, I mean, step by step and its weird.

So in the Fragment with the RecyclerView I register the Event and call the fragment.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)){
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
    }
}

 @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.ASYNC)
 fun onMessageEvent(event: TEvent?) {
    adapter?.addItems(event?.model!!);
    adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The Adapter :

```
fun addItems(model: SubCategoryModel){
    dataM.run {
        add(model)
        if(dataM.isNotEmpty()){
            text.visibility = View.GONE;
            imageView.visibility = View.GONE;
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment B where I fill the form with the information

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(TEvent(model))
activity?.onBackPressed()
```

Before using the EventBus I was using a Dialog in the same Fragment and it worked but now, it only updates the list if the app is running in a debug mode.

How can I update the other fragment thread ?

Comment: in which life method you are unregistering eventbus?

Comment: I was using onStop but it was removing as soon as the new fragment opens

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update `UI` from `MAIN` threadMode instead of `ASYNC`

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onMessageEvent(event: TEvent?) {
     adapter?.addItems(event?.model!!);
     adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**UPDATE**

May be swapping the post statement

```
activity?.onBackPressed() // makes receiver fragment start
EventBus.getDefault().post(TEvent(model))
```

Comment: maybe because the addItem runs dataM.run {}

Comment: try swapping the statements as mentioned in updated answer

Comment: same problem. .

Comment: Any Suggestions ?

Comment: same issue, anyone got solution?